# Why is it not allowed to use UNION in an Indexed View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

According to this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751838/create-an-index-on-sql-view-with-union-operators-will-it-really-improve-perform) and to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) it is not possible to use the UNION keyword when designing an Indexed view.

But **why** is it technically an issue for DBMS?

In this case, could be very useful to be allowed to add an index on VUnion(ID):

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE T2 (ID INT, Info NVARCHAR(1000))

CREATE VIEW VUnion
AS
SELECT ID FROM T1
    UNION
SELECT ID FROM T2
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the "why" technicalities, probably only the Microsoft developers on the SQL-Server project can shed full light on that.

But why don't you have another table, say `T0` which will hold all the `IDs` that are in either of the 2 tables? You could even have Foreign Key constraints, from `T1` and `T2`, referencing that `T0` table.

Of course that would mean extra work for your Insert and Delete procedures on the 2 tables but the problem is solved: you'll have the primary key on `T0 (id)` which means automatically an index on it.

Comment: That's what I would do. Using triggers or custom well-trimmed store procedures. It seems a bit overkill for such a _simple_ aim. But I obvioulsy miss something when I assert "_simple"_.